# Kickstart from USB and Exclude the USB drive for Installation

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, kickstart, installer-anaconda

During the installation my script is searching all the disks of the system.

Usually the USB is assigned with sda.

What would be the most appropriate way to prevent the USB disk as a candidate disk for the installation?

1. Identify the disk of the USB during the installation and exclude it?
2. Add a check in the script to exclude any removable device?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all i need to be sure, are you using **2 USBs** to install or just one?
(one USB bootable for installation and the other for the Kickstart)

1. You don't need the script to identify USB disks why? because the system filter the removable disks alphabetically **sda1,sda2,sdb1,sdb2** and the first USB is sda1 and the second is sda2 and so on.
2. To exclude the USB drive you just need to add this line in the Kickstart file:

   ```
   ignoredisk --drives=sda
   ```

**just a side note:**

- if you have troubles identifying USB drives, make sure that the format of the USB is FAT32 (i'm not talking about the bootable USB).